VPN connection and 2FA, microsoft verification code
My organization uses 2FA with the microsoft system, and each time I want to make VPN connection to the network of the company, I have to enter a microsoft verification code, which is sent to me as an SMS.
When I try to VPN using the standard VPN GUI of ubuntu, I first enter the credentials, and then ubuntu asks me for the verification code, but does not provide a field where this code can be entered (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, Gnome version 42.9), and thus I cannot establish the connection. Do I miss something or it is a gui bag?
UPD:
In short, the GUI for VPN connection asks for the verification code but does not have a field where one can enter it.

What does is it a gui bag mean?

The GUI asks for the verification code but does not have a field where I can enter it.

Then please edit the question and say that.

What GUI do you use for SSH connection? Normally you just start the ssh command from the terminal.

Sorry, bad on me. I mixed up SSH and VPN. Now, I corrected the question

Some corporate VPNs are (I guess) custom-made and does not work well with Ubuntu.  Have you asked your organisation's IT department to see if there is anything they're doing that is "non-standard"?

I believe that they use a standard solution from Microsoft (Microsoft MFA)
Anyway, just found that I can do the connection using CiscoAnyConnect client
